# Better font for Control Pictures?

Tags: support, code-formatting, markdown

There is a set of thirty-nine Unicode characters used for representing otherwise non-visible characters, U+2400 to U+2426. However, on Stack Overflow they are largely unreadable (though do at least exist).

> ␀␁␂␃␄␅␆␇␈␉␊␋␌␍␎␏␐␑␒␓␔␕␖␗␘␙␚␛␜␝␞␟␠␡␢␣␤␥␦

```
123456789012345678901234567890123456789
␀␁␂␃␄␅␆␇␈␉␊␋␌␍␎␏␐␑␒␓␔␕␖␗␘␙␚␛␜␝␞␟␠␡␢␣␤␥␦
```

Note that in the code block they aren't even fixed-width.

[image: Screenshot from Firefox 68 and Edge 42, Windows 10]

They are more readable in Chrome, by virtue of being even wider.
[image: Screenshot from Chrome 75, Windows 10]

Is there a reliable way to get them big enough to be readable? Ideally for everyone, but I'd settle for just myself.

Comment: Using Firefox on Windows 10, those characters are rendered with the Segoe UI Symbol font, overriding the fonts listed in the CSS. I don't know if this is decided by the browser or the OS.

Comment: Depends on your OS and browser. Chrome on Windows 10 displays them nicely: https://i.stack.imgur.com/4LtOu.png

Comment: @CodeCaster I guess you just answered my question then, it's the browser that decides on how to render them.

Comment: Afaik it's a fallback font to be used if the fonts specified in the CSS don't contain the characters that need to be displayed. Which font is used is browser-specific, but ideally you wouldn't rely on this fallback. If SO did specify a monospace font that contained these characters, it would be fixed, but I'm not sure there is one.

Comment: The only font on my Mac that can actually render *all* of these codepoints is [*Apple Symbols*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apple_Symbols). [*Arial Unicode MS*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arial_Unicode_MS) comes close (2 codepoints missing), followed by the [*PingFang* series of fonts](https://fontsinuse.com/typefaces/46753/pingfang) (6 points missing). That makes it really hard to recommend any better fonts; this is just not an area of the Unicode standard that font-makers care to support. Your browser can only fall back to a font that includes the glyphs.

Comment: You can also see how your browser renders them on Wikipedia also (in a larger font): https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Control_Pictures. On my system, [Lucida Sans Unicode](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/typography/font-list/lucida-sans-unicode) covers all of them except two. I guess Stack Overflow could theoretically use web fonts to allow users to have a font that renders them...

Comment: FF 67 on Win10 displays them horribly.

Comment: @HereticMonkey: The CSS for Wikipedia only asks for 'sans-serif', so a whole font family, but has increased the size of the table rows there with a `font-size:x-large`, hard-coded in the table template (and the table itself has a `font-size:large` applied to it already). You can't do that in general Stack Overflow post bodies.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Definitely! The link to Wikipedia was more for those people (like me) who have poor eyesight and can't make much out of what's shown in the question :).

Comment: @HereticMonkey I can't make it out either, hence my request.

Comment: Yeah, at least yours show diagonally; mine show inline so it's just a long line of undifferentiated letter-like pixel smush.